# How to access elements in external views in titanium alloy?

Tags: android, view, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am making android mobile app on titanium Alloy 1.2.2

I want to access elements contained in external views.
So if I use

```
var win=Alloy.createController().getView();
```

it itself opens that view. I dont need that. I just want to access an element in that view and change its visibility to false. How can we do that? Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can access the child elements of your view, for example if you have your main view and you want to access a label inside another controller which has another view you'll have to do something similar to this: `mainView.children[0].children[0].children[0]`

Answer (score 1):

use `Alloy.createController('name').__views` to get views outside the controller, e.g.:

```
// fruit.xml
<Alloy>
    <View id='opacity_view'></View>
</Alloy>

// other.js: 
the_view = Alloy.createController('fruit').__views.opacity_view
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to export the property but you'll need the reference of your controller which you already have it.

```
var win=Alloy.createController('Path to your controller');
```

In the .js of the controller you need:

```
exports.element = $.elementid;
```

Then you can access `win.element.visible = false` or whatever property you need.

Answer (score 0):

`controller.getView()` doesn't show view on the screen. Probably in controller which you initialize you have code similar to this: `$.index.open()` which adds new view on device screen.

If you want to hide element when view is created the best way is to create .tss file where you put rule: `visible: false` using either `#id` or `.class`.

Check more in [Alloy Styles and Themes documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes).